# UWP application not working in VS 2017

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to open my UWP application in VS 2017. According to [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/03/07/visual-studio-2017-now-ready-windows-application-development-needs/) site it should work.

The UpgradeLog.htm file says: *The application which this project type is based on was not found.*

Visual Studio shows the project as incompatible and states: *This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.*

I do have UWP installed per the VS 2017 installation dialog. I am using the professional edition if this matters. This application only targets tablets and desktops.

Comment: Did you start this app from the basic uwp app template that came with VS 2015? Or did you create this app from an extension and/or downloaded template?

Comment: I started it from the basic template in 2015. I may have found the solution and will update if so.

Comment: Have you tried any other solutions? Or creating a new blank UWP app? Do these work?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new UWP project using VS 2017. I compared the `csproj` files to see what might be the difference. I noticed that the `ProjectTypeGuids` each contained two guids. The first guid was different between the two however the second was the same.

So, I changed the first guid: `{BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}` became `{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A}`.

I still received errors including *version string portion was too short or too long*. For this I changed the `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` to 14, updated the `Project ToolsVersion` to 15, and added the `TargetPlatformIdentifier` with a value of *UAP*. All these changes were needed as it didn't work until I had done all of these.

After this I could load the project however I see errors loading runtime libraries. This is still an issue however the project loads now which was the original scope of my question. I'll work on the remaining errors separately.

Comment: That is strange. VS should be able to update the project to the necessary new version. Did you have a specific runtime target? Perhaps you can retarget the project particular uwp runtime? Are you able to upgrade other types of projects (non-uwp)?

Comment: All other projects work fine and this is my only app like this. I think the problem is that the target was Windows 8.1 as this was an RT application that hasn't been touched in a long time. I never did get this thing working. I think I'll try and go back to VS 2015 and update the target.

Answer (score 0):

this guid {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3} refers to a windows 8.1 application.

All of the VS project guids can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/%2FReference%2F720512%2FList-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)

What you need to do is upgrade your project from win8 to win10 .   You can do this manually by converting some of the project guids and adding more metadata, like described in the other answer you gave.   As long as you make sure to cover all the required steps, you should be golden.

But your best bet is to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project) doc which takes you step by step on how to convert a win8 project to win10.

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced the csproj file with older version and it worked for me.